# How to include a Provider(s) within widget testing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a Widget that relies on a provider.  I want to run widget tests on this widget.  I assume because widget testing is directly at that node in the tree, it is reasonable to get errors such as:

```
  * Ensure the Provider<Appointments> is an ancestor to this InstallMonitorPage Widget
```

(note: the name of my Provider is .  May main includes:

```
 return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthBase>(
          builder: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
        Provider<Appointments>(
          builder: (context) => Appointments(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: title,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: LaunchPage()),
    );
```

Is there a syntax/way to include the Provider when running a widget test on a widget lower down the widget tree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
         providers: [
        Provider<AuthBase>(
          builder: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
        Provider<Appointments>(
          builder: (context) => Appointments(),
         )
       ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (_) => YourWidgeToTest(),
      ),
    ),);
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I try this (```builder: (_) => MaterialApp(
              home: InstallMonitorPage(),
            ),``` I go down the rabbit hole of ```The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 106 pixels on the bottom.

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.```  I try wrapping with a variety of flexible and extended widgets, but must be clueless.  Is there an obvious way to track down this challenge?

Comment: well, it's look like is an error with your layout, remember when you test your app it runs in a different screen size 'simulator'